# Problems with list iterator and - operator

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why my list iterator hates .end()-1 ? I want to iterato to one before the list end, I was under the impression you could always do this !

Code on request

```
std::list<Hammer::shared_ptr<Hammer::Actor>> collisionActorsList;

std::list<Hammer::shared_ptr<Hammer::Actor>>::iterator _actorUpdateIter =           collisionActorsList.begin();
while(_actorUpdateIter != (collisionActorsList.end()-1)) // ERROR HERE
{
    // check against every other actor 
    std::list<Hammer::shared_ptr<Hammer::Actor>>::iterator _otherActorsUpdateIter =  _actorUpdateIter+1; // ERROR HERE TOO
    while(_otherActorsUpdateIter != collisionActorsList.end())
    {// SOME STUFF }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that demonstrates this alleged hatred?

Comment: sure , its heavily convoluted though, will try.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing `-` with `--`.  You can decrement an iterator that is at the end.

Comment: @jeffmagill No, I am not, I want to iterate to 1 before the end of the list

Answer (score 3):

`std::list` uses a bidirectional iterator, which doesn't support `operator-` or `operator+`. Use `std::prev(collisionActorsList.end())` and `std::next(_actorUpdateIter)`.

As pointed out below in the comments, you should be aware of whether your list is empty. If it is, these will fail to do what you want. There's a simple function for that: `collisionActorsList.empty()`.

Comment: N.B: [`std::prev()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) is only available since C++11.

Comment: Doing "while(_actorUpdateIter != std::prev(collisionActorsList.end()))" causes a runtime Assertion saying "list Iterator is not decrementable"

Comment: @angryInsomniac, I'm not sure why. Bidirectional iterators are decrementable.

Comment: @chris ah ! well, I guess something else is wrong ?! I cant imagine what though.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, True, though it's easy to roll your own in 03 (or just declare it before and decrement it). The documentation page gives a sample implementation as well :)

Comment: @angryInsomniac: Is your list empty?  If it is, then decrementing from the end iterator(which is also the begin iterator) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @angryInsomniac using `std::prev()` causes a **runtime** assertion? are you sure the list isn't empty? You said (`list.end()-1)` hates you, but never elaborated as to how that hatred is expressed? *Compile-time* hatred tells me the *code* is wrong. *Runtime* hatred tells me the ***logic*** is wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That was the issue, the list was empty and decrementing it caused UB.